# Dynamic tracing of all event handler registrations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, prototypal-inheritance

My goal is to dynamically trace all registrations of event handlers in JavaScript, including but not limited to the document and window object. A piece of code is supposed to run before the rest of the website executes (onLoad) and should report what functions register for events. I want to wrap `addEventListener`, `onmouseclick`, `onmessage` etc. but I don't want to do this for each object individually.

I was looking into modifying the behavior of `Object.constructor` to perform self-inspection in the constructor. The code should be pretty trivial and look roughly like this:

```
var toWrap = [ "addEventListener", "onclick", "..." ];

for ( var x in toWrap ) {
    if ( toWrap[x] in this ) {
        this[toWrap[x]] = wrap(toWrap[x], this[toWrap[x]]);
    }
}
```

... but what is the right place to plug the code?

A pure JavaScript solution would be preferred over jQuery etc., I am implementing in PhantomJS.

**Update:**

I came up with the following code after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623624/2125578). It seems to work fine - any objections?

```
Object = ( function ( ) {
    this.wrap = function(e) {
        // ....
    }   
    this.wrap();
});
```

Comment: `Object.prototype.constructor === Object`

Comment: Good point, I looked into Object.constructor as well, but every attempt broke all the JS execution in Phantom

Comment: Not that I'd recommend it, but if you want to overwrite native methods for handler assignment, you'd need to do it on the prototype of the elements, like `Element.prototype`. You won't have success with trying to modify constructors themselves. Also, there's no `onclick` method. It's a simple property. But I'd wonder why you want/need this in the first place.

Comment: @sillylittleme so how would I catch all handlers? Why: I want to pick out specific functions to run static analysis on them.