# Convert global function into static utility in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Shape class, it's defined in the global scope:

```
function Shape(t) {
   this.type;                            
   Shape.prototype.init = function(){
      this.type = t;
      //more work here             
   }
   this.init();                                         
}
```

I want to consolidate all global functions/classes into a single class to avoid conflicts with global namespace

```
function Util(){}
Util.Shape = function(){...}
Util.Point = function(){...}
```

That works, but I don't like repeating `Util.` each time, so I use a property like a namespace for related functions, in this case, `math:`

```
Util.math = {
   Shape: function(t) {
      this.type;                            
      Shape.prototype.init = function(){
         this.type = t; 
         //more work here            
      }
      this.init();                                         
   },
   Point: function(t) {...}
}
```

But that doesn't work; complains about `this.init()`; makes sense since `Shape.prototype` is not needed here, so it's removed:

```
Util.math = {
   Shape: function(t) {
      this.type;                            
      this.init = function(){
         this.type = t;             
      }
      this.init();                                         
   }
}
```

Works now:

```
var square = new Util.math.Shape('square');
var circle = new Util.math.Shape('circle');         
console.log(square.type);  // 'square'
console.log(circle.type);  // 'circle'
```

**Questions:

Any issue with this approach? More effective/cleaner way to do it?**

**Also, why does this not work?** (this is [coolness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741154/791406))

```
Util.math = {
   Shape: function(t) {
      this.type;                            
      this.init = function(){
         this.type = t;             
      }                                         
   }.init(); //<------coolness
}
```

Comment: `But that doesn't work; complains about this.init()` because a function expression is different to a function declaration. `makes sense since Shape.prototype is not needed here`—if it's "not needed here" then it was not needed before.

Comment: I believe you are correct,

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
var myLib = (function() {

  var obj = {};

  function Shape(t) {
    this.init(t);
  }

  Shape.prototype.init = function(t){
     this.type = t;
  }

  obj.Shape = Shape;

  // more stuff

  return obj;
}());

var shape = new myLib.Shape('circle');

console.log(shape.type); // circle
```

Assuming that the *init* thing is just an example.

Comment: Interesting, so `obj` is like a type store?

Comment: Yes, have a look at how the real [MyLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib-downloads.html) is put together.